# swift3 - how do I access dictionary in an array?

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to make an array of several dictionaries for my world clock app like this:

```
let countriesList = [
    ["country": "Tokyo, Japan", "gmc": "GMT+9"],
    ["country": "New York, USA", "gmc": "GMT-5"]
]
```

Since I'm getting no error, I'm assuming this is okay. 
Now my question is, how do I access each country? 
I'm trying to list them all into a table, and I have googled but I got nothing. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's highly recommended  to use a custom struct for that purpose:

```
struct Country {
    let name, gmc : String
}

let countriesList = [
    Country(name: "Tokyo, Japan", gmc: "GMT+9"),
    Country(name: "New York", gmc: "GMT-5")
]
```

Now in `cellForRow` you can easily access the properties:

```
let country = countriesList[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = country.name
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = country.gmc
```

No key subscription, no type casting, no optional binding, no problems ;-)

You can print all the names with

```
print(countryList.map{ $0.name })
```

Comment: oh this is awesome! So much better than the code I had originally.
I was trying not to use hardcoded string for my name and gmc but I didn't know how, and it didn't let me using variables, so this is awesome! Thank you for teaching me this coding style, I can definitely use it from now on!!!

Comment: Since I'm a newbie and I have just started learning Swift, I think I like this style the best because it's the safest. For this purpose, I will mark this as solved, but I also liked the other's posts because I have also learned a new coding style. Thank you all, so much for being so nice, even though this post might have been too "newbie"

Comment: Well, if it will be used just in this little array, even `tuple` will do.

Comment: @user28434 Apple says: *If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple*

Comment: @vadian, `if it will be used just in this little array`, isn't it *temporary scope* by definition?

Comment: @user28434 In the *scope* of the question, yes, but the OP wants *to list them all into a table*.

Answer (score 2):

In your `cellForRowAt` method where you are setting country to label.

```
cell.lblCountry.text = self.countriesList[indexPath.row]["country"] as? String
```

If you want all country list from your array of dictionary.

```
let countries = self.countriesList.flatMap { $0["country"] as? String }
```

With this you will get array of string with all `country` value.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! This worked perfectly!!!
I will mark this as solved, but it says I gotta wait 9 minutes :D

Comment: @kimmo Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use subscript:

```
for country in countriesList {
    print(country["country"])
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is just a basic sample answering only your question. Accepted answer is much more useful, although the struct is missing an initializer, which should be failable, especially if you initialize from JSON response.
Take a look at what map really does, to understand it better, flatMap for removing optionality layer, etc